# Java ImageIO work on W10 but not W8

Tags: java, image, reader

So I wrote this program to read an image and change some of it's colors:

```
public class MorphImage {
    private final String URL = "pic1.jpg";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new MorphImage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public MorphImage() throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = readImage(URL);
    pointOp(image, 50, 75);
}

/**
 * Read and create a bufferedImage from an URL.
 * 
 * @param URL
 * @return
 */
private BufferedImage readImage(String URL) {
    URL url = getClass().getResource(URL);
    File file = new File(url.getPath());
    BufferedImage bimg = null;
    try {
        bimg = ImageIO.read(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bimg;

}

/**
 * Uses a BufferedImage to create a new copy of it with altered values.
 * 
 * @param img
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void pointOp(BufferedImage img, int con, int brig) throws IOException {
    int width = img.getWidth();
    int height = img.getHeight();
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    WritableRaster inraster = img.getRaster();
    WritableRaster outraster = image.getRaster();
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            int value = inraster.getSample(i, j, 0);
            outraster.setSample(i, j, 0, 255 - value);
        }
    ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("Morphed " + URL));
    System.out.println("Morphed");

}


}
```

It work great on my laptop running Windows 10, but when I cloned the repo unto my pc running Windows 8.1, it can't find the the image "pic1.jpg" anymore. It throws IIOException Can't read input file. Both computers are running identical setups of JDK and Eclipse. I got all my files in the same package:

```
imager
      -src
         -main
             -MorphImage.java
             -pic1.jpg
```

Do anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: Probably the working directory is set differently. By default it would be project dir - `imager`, so the picture should be saved under `imager/pic.jpg`

Comment: Yes I know, the images do get save directly in the projectfolder. But on my pc running 8.1 I can't even read the picture to begin with. Could it have something with permissions to do?

Comment: Hmm, it could have something to do with permissions. Is your project folder located under your `User` folder? Also, you may want to try moving the file inside the `main/resources` folder.